# jQuery Submit function wont post the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently facing a difficulty with jQuery post function where i using some other example on the google. I had try to search around in stackoverflow for the solution but sadly i'm too poor to find out the error.

Here is the sample of jQuery which i used to do for the confirm box:

```
   (function ($) {

    /**
     * Confirm a link or a button
     * @param [options] {{title, text, confirm, cancel, confirmButton, cancelButton, post, confirmButtonClass}}
     */
    $.fn.confirm = function (options) {
        if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
            options = {};
        }

        this.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var newOptions = $.extend({
                button: $(this)
            }, options);

            $.confirm(newOptions, e);
        });

        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Show a confirmation dialog
     * @param [options] {{title, text, confirm, cancel, confirmButton, cancelButton, post, confirmButtonClass}}
     * @param [e] {Event}
     */
    $.confirm = function (options, e) {
        // Do nothing when active confirm modal.
        if ($('.confirmation-modal').length > 0)
            return;

        // Parse options defined with "data-" attributes
        var dataOptions = {};
        if (options.button) {
            var dataOptionsMapping = {
                'title': 'title',
                'text': 'text',
                'confirm-button': 'confirmButton',
                'cancel-button': 'cancelButton',
                'confirm-button-class': 'confirmButtonClass',
                'cancel-button-class': 'cancelButtonClass'
            };
            $.each(dataOptionsMapping, function(attributeName, optionName) {
                var value = options.button.data(attributeName);
                if (value) {
                    dataOptions[optionName] = value;
                }
            });
        }

        // Default options
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.confirm.options, {
            confirm: function () {
                var url = e && (('string' === typeof e && e) || (e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.attributes['href'].value));
                if (url) {
                    if (options.post) {
                        var form = $('<form method="post" class="hide" action="' + url + '"></form>');
                        $("body").append(form);
                        form.submit();
                    } else {
                        window.location = url;
                    }
                }
            },
            cancel: function (o) {
            },
            button: null
        }, dataOptions, options);

        // Modal
        var modalHeader = '';
        if (settings.title !== '') {
            modalHeader =
                '<div class=modal-header>' +
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                    '<h4 class="modal-title">' + settings.title+'</h4>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        var modalHTML =
                '<div class="confirmation-modal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">' +
                    '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                        '<div class="modal-content">' +
                            modalHeader +
                            '<div class="modal-body">' + settings.text + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                                '<button class="confirm btn ' + settings.confirmButtonClass + '" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">' +
                                    settings.confirmButton +
                                '</button>' +
                                '<button class="cancel btn ' + settings.cancelButtonClass + '" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">' +
                                    settings.cancelButton +
                                '</button>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

        var modal = $(modalHTML);

        modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            modal.find(".btn-primary:first").focus();
        });
        modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            modal.remove();
        });
        modal.find(".confirm").click(function () {
            settings.confirm(settings.button);
        });
        modal.find(".cancel").click(function () {
            settings.cancel(settings.button);
        });

        // Show the modal
        $("body").append(modal);
        modal.modal('show');
    };
```

Here is the php file i used to submit my form and confirmation box:

```
                    <form role="form" action="bannerConfig.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <label for="bannerWidth">Width 宽度</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="bannerWidth" id="bannerWidth" placeholder="600px" onChange="checkDisabled(simpleConfirm);">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="bannerHeight">Height 高度</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="bannerHeight" id="bannerHeight" placeholder="280px" onChange="checkDisabled(simpleConfirm);">
                                </div>

                                <p class="help-block">Recommended Banner Size: (1920px * 500px)</p>                     

                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <button id="simpleConfirm" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Update</button>        
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->


                        </form>     

<!--Banner configuration confirmation-->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#simpleConfirm").confirm();
            }); 
        </script>
```

Everytime i clicked "Yes" which it supposed to post and link me to bannerConfig.php but it just nothing happen when i click "Yes". Is there any code that i mistakely put? Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

EDITED: Here is my server side php code:

```
<?php
    include 'dbConnection.php';

    global $dbLink;
    //Gather all required data
    $width = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerWidth']);
    $height = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerHeight']);

    //Create the SQL query
    //$query = "INSERT INTO banner_config (banner_id, banner_height, banner_width, date) VALUES ('','{$height}', {$width}, NOW())";
    $query = "UPDATE banner_config SET banner_height = '$height', banner_width = '$width', date=NOW()";
    //Execute the query
    $result = $dbLink->query($query);
        //Check if it was successfull

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();

?>
```

Comment: there has to be other jquery we are not being shown here

Comment: FYI , i now posted the whole jQuery code there.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, i was wanted to on submit then post the value and insert into database. But what i face now is it nothing happen when i'm trying to click "Yes". Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: you are creating an empty form and is submitting that... instead I think you should provide a callback method for `confirm` and the form submit should happen there

Comment: @ArunPJohny May i knw what you mean by provide a callback method for confirm? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the problem is, you are creating a dynamic form and is submitting it without any input data instead of submitting the form in which the button is present.

I think the actual form submission logic can be done using a callback. like

```
    // Default options
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.confirm.options, {
        confirm: $.noop,
        cancel: function (o) {},
        button: null
    }, dataOptions, options);
```

then

```
$("#simpleConfirm").confirm({
    confirm: function (el) {
        el.closest('form').submit()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3zvm2ovd/1/)

---

Another option is to find the form in which the button is present then submit it like

```
    // Default options
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.confirm.options, {
        confirm: function () {
            var $form = $(e.target).closest('form');
            var url = $form.attr('action');
            if (url) {
                if (options.post) {
                    $form.submit();
                } else {
                    window.location = url;
                }
            }
        },
        cancel: function (o) {},
        button: null
    }, dataOptions, options);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3zvm2ovd/2/)

Comment: Oh, Thanks! It work like a charm. Is there any possible i still can add ajax function on the form submit which prevent the page to reloading?

Comment: which version are you using? in the first version instead of using `el.closest('form').submit()`, you can have your ajax call

Comment: i'm using the first version, what is the best way to have ajax call when my form is successfully submitted to popup message/show a hidden div? Thanks alot

Comment: May i ask why do we need this 
   $.ajax({
                url: 'bannerConfig.php',
When we already have the <form role="form" action="bannerConfig.php" method="POST">

Will it be duplicate link to call?

Comment: @MarcusTan no,... we are not using the default form submit...  so that shouldn't matter...

Comment: Hi there, i have a problem with the code, my database only insert the date only, my width and height value does become 0.
Is that the ajax problem?

Comment: I had posted the server side code on the above. Previously when using your version 1, everything work great. but when added the ajax function... it only update my Date, but my height and width attribute become 0. Is there anything i have to add on my server side?

Comment: can you change the type of the input element to text from number and try

Comment: also try to echo the values in the server side to see whether the values are reaching server... also add `alert('el:'+el.attr('id'))
            alert('len:'+el.closest('form').length)
            alert('params:'+el.closest('form').serialize())
` before the ajax call...

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your code, yes it can reach the server...every alert came out the correct attribute value, but why only the width and height attribute value become 0 when insert into database?

Comment: @MarcusTan not a PHP guy so not sure why? can you try to echo the values in the server side and see whether it is proper... also can you share the data type of the column... also the value in the 3rd alert

Comment: The data type for both width and height is INT and the value for the 3rd alert is params:bannerWidth=123&bannerHeight=123

Comment: Not sure why, i changed the $width = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerWidth']);
 $height = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerHeight']);
to
$width = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_GET['bannerWidth']);
 $height = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_GET['bannerHeight']);

Then it all work well now...but don't it feel weird when my client side is using post and my server side using GET to get the value? Sorry for my poor php and client side understanding.

Comment: can you use the `network` tab of your browser's developer tools to check the request sent to the server to see whether it is of type get/post

Comment: It was a GET type. :)

Comment: @MarcusTan my mistake, it should be `type: 'post'` not `method: 'post'` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3zvm2ovd/6/

Comment: Oic, thanks for all the guidance , million thanks for helping me out

Comment: Hi may i ask more about the javascript part. When i successfully submited the form. Can my alert box came out and alert user then when user click okay, then the page will be reloard and the text field will be empty?

I had try with this:

.done(function () {
       //do something if you want when the post is successfull
       if(!alert('Alert For your User!')){window.location.reload();}

The page can be refresh, but the number still stick to the text field. Any idea?

Comment: there is no need to have a `if` condition there... try to set `autocomplete='off'` to the input element

Comment: also I think you can post a new question regarding that... I'm not sure about a solution for that... so somebody else could answer you